# Impact analysis through ANOVA

Tags: anova, experiment-design, business-intelligence

Consider this scenario : Acme inc. processes tickets every day. The ticket completion time range in the order of few days-weeks. Acme hires a new manager Wile E Coyote.

We collect the data for the previous few months before Wile was hired (ie tickets vs completion times). And then some more data for the next few months after he was hired.

1. Can we use ANOVA test to determine Wile made an impact ?
2. How should we group the data ? Can we divide the data by bins of 1 month each ?
3. How many months of data should we analyze ?
4. What are the threshold values for F ? How to arrive at those numbers ? (ie) Can we say something like:

   "If F < 0.4, then no impact. If F > 2, then significant impact. If 0.4 < F < 2, then neither"

*Update*

My real use case is, I have a ticketing system. I want to let the users define "custom events" on an any date and measure the impact before and after. The events could be something like "introduced a new process", "reassigned staff", "bought new equipment", "natural disaster led to some change in processes" etc.

Comment: Do tickets come in more often during certain months?

Comment: Lets say that no of tickets per month is mostly even

Comment: Then to answer question 2, you do not need to divide the data by bins of 1 month each. You can just group it by before Wile's hiring vs. after Wile's hiring. However you might want to take into account that when Wile is still new to the company, it may not accurately represent his long-term performance.

Comment: Good point sheep, I updated the question. With this new information, how would it affect question #2 ?

Comment: Suppose it takes people 2 weeks to get used to the new setting, then I would take out the data from the 2 weeks right after the new event has occurred, and consider only the data after the 2 weeks in terms of long term impact for the ANOVA.

Comment: How many weeks of data should we consider for the previous (before event) groups ? This is a long running system that has about 10 years worth of data.

Comment: How often do events occur? If they're really close together compared to the time it takes for everyone to get used to the new setting, then it would difficult to differentiate the effect of one event from another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30034/discussion-between-sheep-and-md-luffy).